# VS2012 Express unable to start correctly in Surface Pro

Tags: windows-8, crash, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-surface

I have recently bought surface pro. It is running on a 64-bit Windows 8 OS running on Intel i5-3317U with 4GB RAM. By all standards as far as I know it should be able run any program I can run on my desktop and laptop, right?

I have downloaded VS2012 Express for Desktop and installed it fine. When I run it however, it gives the error "Program is unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)". I have VS2012 ultimate running on my desktop. Any programs I compile with it is unable to run on my Surface with that error, even simple "hello world" programs.

I thought it was something I'm doing wrong with the coding at first but even when the IDE does not run... I'm out of ideas.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. VS2012 is Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 for those that are not familiar with IDEs

Comment: There is an error log you should post that

Comment: Error `0xc000007b` means `INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492037/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b